# SQL join and group problem

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

First to say I'm using mySQL and my only way of accessing database is over phpMyAdmin since this is for a website.

First I have a table of users like this (table1):

```
user_id | name
--------------
      1 | Mike
      2 | Johny
      3 | Bob
```

and another table about their season results (table2):

```
user_id | season | result
-------------------------
      1 | 2009   |     10
      1 | 2010   |      8
      1 | 2011   |      5
      2 | 2009   |      7
      2 | 2010   |      3
      3 | 2009   |      1
```

And now I want out the user's name and his last season's result, so something like this:

```
user_id | name | season | result
--------------------------------
      1 | Mike |   2011 |      5
      2 | Johny|   2010 |      3
      3 | Bob  |   2009 |      1
```

The closest I have come to something like this was

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.user_id = table2.user_id GROUP BY id
```

But I cannot provide that I want the newest season and it just uses a random one.
Anyone has any ideas how to do this?

best regards,
Rok

Comment: You want to ignore Mikes results from 2009 and 2010, because there are results in 2011?

Comment: Yes, it's kinda like archive and I need just the results from the last season that user competed in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1, table2,
(SELECT user_id AS lUserid, MAX(season) AS lSeason FROM table2 GROUP BY user_id) AS lTable2
WHERE table1.user_id = table2.user_id
AND table2.user_id = lTable2.lUserid
AND table2.season = lTablle2.lSeason
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to order them by Season column?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.user_id = table2.user_id GROUP BY id ORDER BY season DESC
```